# if elseif statement not working php

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

so i have these two stored procedures. the first one works properly, but the second wont. it still executes the first one. i tried commenting out the others except the second stored proc and it works fine. what am i doing wrong here?

```
if($view='group'){
$sql = "CALL sp_edit_biochem_group('$item_group_ID','$item_group_code','$item_group_desc','$item_group_qty','$uom','$location','$inv_by','$as_of_date')";
}
elseif ($view='breakdown'){
$sql = "CALL sp_edit_biochem_breakdown('$status','$as_of_date','$serial_no','$item_breakdown_ID')";
}
```

Comment: Classic: use `==` instead of `=`. `=` assigns a value and `==` compares values. Also take a look at "[Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)" to avoid such problems.

Comment: Should you be using `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: You're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==`.

Comment: I'm disturbed that I typed almost that exact same string as a comment, at exactly the same time as you were typing it as an answer. Are you enjoying the view from inside my head? :D

Comment: @andrewsi There are scary things in there, for sure...  =)

Answer (score 2):

You're using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of the equality operator (`==`). Try:

```
if($view=='group'){
    $sql = "CALL sp_edit_biochem_group('$item_group_ID','$item_group_code','$item_group_desc','$item_group_qty','$uom','$location','$inv_by','$as_of_date')";
}
elseif ($view=='breakdown'){
    $sql = "CALL sp_edit_biochem_breakdown('$status','$as_of_date','$serial_no','$item_breakdown_ID')";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the reason why it's recommended to use:

```
if ('group' == $view) {
```

If you made a mistake like the one you did (using `=` instead of `==`), your code would look like this:

```
if ('group' = $view) {
```

You would get a fatal error, and notice + fix the issue immediately.

Comment: I've never seen this recommended, although it makes sense (where one side is constant). Can you cite a source?

Comment: one second, I think it's in PSR-2 or something :D

Comment: @AdrianWragg It's called Yoda condition. Here's a little text on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions)

Comment: Yes, it's not in PSR, sorry about that. I first saw it as a wordpress recommended standard (http://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#ternary-operator)